# Is there a way to change tsconfig to ignore certain libraries?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

My codebase is a mix of typescript + javascript. When importing a javascript library into a typescript library, i just use the // @ts-ignore. But i'm using this javascript library quite frequently and it's been tedious to constantly put //@ts-ignore on top of the import. Is there a way to globally ignore the non-ts libraries?

```
//@ts-ignore
import jsLibraryThing from "@jsLibraryThing"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a declaration file for this library that just exports `any`. This will allow you to import it without any error and the import will be typed as `any` so you can use it almost like in JS

```
// jsLibraryThing.d.ts
declare module '@jsLibraryThing' {
    const e: any;
    export default e
 }

//usage.ts
import jsLibraryThing from "@jsLibraryThing"
jsLibraryThing.something // all fine
```